# How to store zoom of Direct2D window when using WM_MOUSEWHEEL message handling

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I'm trying to zoom in out of my `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* renderTarget`-window at the mouse position using the Direct2D helper functions. After some testing I've discovered that `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam)` returns 120 (int? short?) for each mousewheel click.

But now  need to know how to store my zoom level. Because every time I slowly rotate the mousewheel, the zoomfactor will be 1.1 (=1 + 0.1 * 120 / 120) and the image grow 10% but not further. It should be something like zoom = zoom + deltazoom. But how do store variables in and out of `WindowProc`?

```cpp
#include <d2d1.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        POINT p = { 0 };
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p);
        renderTarget->SetTransform(
            D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale(
                D2D1::SizeF(
                    1.0f + 0.1f * GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam)/120.0f,    // /120.0f to normalize and 0.1 the scale factor
                    1.0f + 0.1f * GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam)/120.0f),
                D2D1::Point2F(p.x, p.y)
            );
        );
        return 0;
    //
    // various other cases
    //
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
}
```

Comment: you're not drawing anything.

Comment: My update&render-loop is in the main body of my program. I've changed the code a bit (no need for begindraw and endraw) and i've some testing i've discovered that `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam)` returns 120 for each click of the mousewheel. So i've narrowed down my problem: how to store the zoom factor.

Comment: Your program must have some global data. Where is `renderTarget` kept? Store the zoom factor in the same place.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks! That's it, added zoom factor to the class that contains my rendertarget as well

Comment: @mca2 You can post an answer to end this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Jonathan Potter, to solution is pretty simple by just adding the zoom factor to the class containing my `renderTarget`

Comment: You can mark the answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.